# input date javascript html (min and max)

Tags: javascript, html

how to set min date as current date in date picker and max date as 30 days after current date? its for a booking form. I  searched everywhere couldn't find any  solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```js
const d = new Date();
const min = d.toISOString().split("T")[0]
date.min = min;
var max = d;
max.setDate(d.getDate() + 30)
date.max = max.toISOString().split("T")[0]
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
```

Comment: @ashnike Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Simply like that:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input")
input.min = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
input.max = new Date(new Date()+2592000000).toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

```html
<input type="date" id="input">
```